# Intercept method with enriched params via javaagent

Tags: java, scala, byte-buddy

Is 
it possible to intercept method call and call this intercepted method with enriched params? 
I my case I have to intercept e.g. logger.info("foo"), enrich message param e.g. "foo.bar" and call logger.info("foo.bar")

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. Using a Java agent, the easiest way of doing this is using `Advice`:

```
class LogAdvice {
  static void onEnter(@Advice.Argument(value = 0, readOnly = false) String message) {
    message = message + ".bar";
  }
}
```

You can now register this advice in your transformer using an `AgentBuilder`:

```
dynamicType.visit(Advice.to(LogAdvice.class).on(named("info")));
```